# Dynamically load data on a store in extjs

Tags: extjs, data-binding, combobox

I have two combo box.

When select first field in the first combo box it should has to to show some store elements and for next field some other store elements. For that here I am creating two different stores and bind them. But Now what I feel is this is not a good practice since Store1 contains the elements of Store2.

Is there any way with one store selective data only shown with the selection of the field of first combobox.

```
 {
     xtype: 'combobox',
     fieldLabel: 'Type',
     store: 'hsg'

     listeners: {
         change: function(combo, value) {
             var Store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 fields: ['id', 'name'],
                 data: [{
                         'id': 1,
                         'name': 'StoreA'
                     },
                     {
                         'id': 2,
                         'name': 'StoreB'
                     },
                     {
                         'id': 3,
                         'name': 'StoreC'
                     },
                     {
                         'id': 4,
                         'name': 'StoreD'
                     },
                     {
                         'id': 5,
                         'name': 'StoreF'
                     }
                 ]
             });

             var Store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 fields: ['id', 'name'],
                 data: [{
                         'id': 1,
                         'name': 'StoreA'
                     },
                     {
                         'id': 2,
                         'name': 'StoreB'
                     }
                 ]
             });
             if (2 == value)
                 combo.up().down('combobox[xscope="storeCombo"]').bindStore(Store1);
             else
                 combo.up().down('combobox[xscope="storeCombo"]').bindStore(Store2);
         }
     }
 }, {
     xtype: 'combobox',
     fieldLabel: 'Store',
     xscope: 'storeCombo',
     itemId: 'Store_Id',
     displayField: 'name',
     valueField: 'id',

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `change` event listener, you can use `Ext.data.Store.filter` method, to filter combobox's store: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-filter

For that, you would need to implement filtering logic at your data source.

Comment: Store1.filter('name', 'StoreA');  only filter with one data. What if I need to load to the store with the data of StoreB???

Comment: @Shiromi Filter will send request to your data source. How filter parameters will be processed, will depend on your implementation.